# Amazon Cognito User Pool with Google federation - How to go through the Google review process?

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I'm adding the Google sign-in feature in my Flutter app that already uses Amazon Cognito to authenticate users with their emails and usernames.

From my understanding, it is realized by creating and configuring an app in Google Cloud and then using it as the Google Federation in the Amazon Cognito User Pool.

I have set them all following the document [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html) and it seems to be working on my local so far. However, if I want to make it to live in Production, Google requires us to proceed with their review for **Authorized JavaScript origins** where I'm setting User Pool hosted domain like `https://<app-name>.auth.ap-northeast-1.amazoncognito.com`.

Here is the thing. AFAIK, the User Pool hosted web contents are not editable except for the logo image and CSS. So, I can't place the files that Google requires there.

How do people handle this situation? The only way to go is to create your own website that implements all auth flows on behalf of Cognito-hosted UI and register that domain in the Cognito User Pool for them to use for authentication?

---

###### [UPDATE]

> Google requires us to proceed with their review for **Authorized JavaScript origins**

This was wrong. When we only use non-sensitive scopes (and Cognito only requires them), we **can** use Google sign-in without review even in production. However, in that case, we **can't** display custom App Name and App Logo set in the GCP console. If we want to do this, "brand-verification" requires us to go though the review in question.

> If your app utilizes only non-sensitive scopes, it is not mandatory for your app to complete the app verification process. However, if you want your app to display an app name and logo on the OAuth consent screen, you will need to complete a lighter-weight verification process known as "brand-verification".
> https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/13463073